# what does "räuml. übertr." mean in dictionaries?

Tags: preposition, abbreviation, dictionary

Recently I am checking prepositions in dictionaries, when talking about spatial meaning for the preposition, there are 2 entries: "**1- räumlich**" AND "**2- räumlich übertr. OR übertragen**" , what does the **second** one mean? what is the difference with first one?

Comment: Please give examples of such prepositions

Comment: It could mean _"vernacularized"_, but as @Hubert mentioned it's hard to tell exactly without a prominent example.

Comment: https://www.dwds.de/wb/in

1- räumlich
1a. mit Dat.  .......................
2- räumlich: übertragen
a) mit Dat. ........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usage of prepositions in German can be mostly divided in four classes: 1. spatial 2. temporal 3. modal 4. causal. Many prepositions are used in more than one class. Following is a clear spatial usage of the preposition **in**:

> **In** der Schublade liegt das Dokument.

The definition "übertragen" is used when it is used symbolic, example:

> **In** der Ruhe liegt die Kraft.

You could say it is a spatial preposition. However "Ruhe" (quiet, silence) is no real world place where something can be there. So you would say it is "räumlich übertragen".